# how to find the ancestors of a particular object

Tags: javascript, arrays, parent-child

```
let obj = {
  "options": [
    {
      "id": "a",
      "name": "a",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "a.1",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "a.1.1",
              "name": "a.1.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.1.2",
              "name": "a.1.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.1.3",
              "name": "a.1.3"
            }
          ]   
        },
        {
          "id": "a.2",
          "name": "a.2",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "a.2.1",
              "name": "a.2.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.2.2",
              "name": "a.2.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.2.3",
              "name": "a.2.3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "a.3",
          "name": "a.3",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "a.3.1",
              "name": "a.3.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.3.2",
              "name": "a.3.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.3.3",
              "name": "a.3.1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "id": "b",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "b.1",
          "name": "b.1",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "b.1.1",
              "name": "b.1.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.1.2",
              "name": "b.1.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.1.3",
              "name": "b.1.3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "b.2",
          "name": "b.2",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "b.2.1",
              "name": "b.2.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.2.2",
              "name": "b.2.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.2.3",
              "name": "b.2.3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "b.3",
          "name": "b.3.1",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "b.3.1",
              "name": "b.3.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.3.2",
              "name": "b.3.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.3.3",
              "name": "b.3.3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "c",
      "name": "c",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "c.1",
          "name": "c.1",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "c.1.1",
              "name": "c.1.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.1.2",
              "name": "c.1.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.1.3",
              "name": "c.1.3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "c.2",
          "name": "c.2",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "c.2.1",
              "name": "c.2.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.2.2",
              "name": "c.2.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.2.3",
              "name": "c.2.3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "c.3",
          "name": "c.3",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "c.3.1",
              "name": "c.3.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.3.2",
              "name": "c.3.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.3.3",
              "name": "c.3.3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

" I have this object
I neeed to create a function getHierarchy, that an option ID as its input, finds the option in the
list and returns the ID of all it's parents.

for example,getHierarchy("a.1.3") should return the following result ["a","a.1","a.1.3"]
getHierarchy("c.3.3") should return the following result ["c","c.3","c.3.3"] "

Answer (score 0):

assuming id is unique;

```
function getHierarchy(object, id, prev) {
    if (!object.options) return;
    for (const child of object.options) {
        if(child.id === id) {
            return [...prev, object.id, child.id];
        }
        result = getHierarchy(child, id, [...prev, object.id]);
       if (result) return result;
    }
}
getHierarchy(obj, "a.1.3", []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an recursive solution i hope this helps you.

```js
let obj = {
  "options": [
    {
      "id": "a",
      "name": "a",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "a.1",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "a.1.1",
              "name": "a.1.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.1.2",
              "name": "a.1.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.1.3",
              "name": "a.1.3"
            }
          ]   
        },
        {
          "id": "a.2",
          "name": "a.2",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "a.2.1",
              "name": "a.2.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.2.2",
              "name": "a.2.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.2.3",
              "name": "a.2.3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "a.3",
          "name": "a.3",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "a.3.1",
              "name": "a.3.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.3.2",
              "name": "a.3.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "a.3.3",
              "name": "a.3.1"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "b",
      "id": "b",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "b.1",
          "name": "b.1",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "b.1.1",
              "name": "b.1.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.1.2",
              "name": "b.1.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.1.3",
              "name": "b.1.3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "b.2",
          "name": "b.2",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "b.2.1",
              "name": "b.2.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.2.2",
              "name": "b.2.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.2.3",
              "name": "b.2.3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "b.3",
          "name": "b.3.1",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "b.3.1",
              "name": "b.3.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.3.2",
              "name": "b.3.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "b.3.3",
              "name": "b.3.3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "id": "c",
      "name": "c",
      "options": [
        {
          "id": "c.1",
          "name": "c.1",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "c.1.1",
              "name": "c.1.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.1.2",
              "name": "c.1.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.1.3",
              "name": "c.1.3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "c.2",
          "name": "c.2",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "c.2.1",
              "name": "c.2.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.2.2",
              "name": "c.2.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.2.3",
              "name": "c.2.3"
            }
          ]
        },
        {
          "id": "c.3",
          "name": "c.3",
          "options": [
            {
              "id": "c.3.1",
              "name": "c.3.1"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.3.2",
              "name": "c.3.2"
            },
            {
              "id": "c.3.3",
              "name": "c.3.3"
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

function getHierarchy(opts, path, index = 1, result = []) {
  if(!opts) return result;
  let objPaths = path.split(".");
  let _path = objPaths.slice(0, index).join(".");
  let option = opts.find(({id}) => id === _path);
  if(!option) return result;
  let { options, id } = option;
  return getHierarchy(options, path, ++index, [...result,id]);
}

let result = getHierarchy(obj.options, "a.1.3");

console.log(result);
```